# Showing private files inside filamentPHP admin panel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I would like to know if there is any way of showing private uploaded files inside filamentPHP admin panel.
Only the authenticated user should be able to see it, since it is not in the public storage folder of Laravel. Their documentation does not seem to include it.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the [Sushi](https://github.com/calebporzio/sushi) package.

1. Install Sushi with composer.
2. Create a wrapper for the private files as a model.

*app/Models/PrivateFilesWrapper.php*

```
class PrivateFilesWrapper extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use Sushi;

    public function getRows(): array
    {
        $files = Storage::disk('private_disk')->allFiles();

        $rows = Arr::map($files, function (string $value, string $key) {
            $size = Storage::disk('private_disk')->size($value);
            $date = Storage::disk('private_disk')->lastModified($value);

            return [
                'name' => $value,
                'date' => $date,
                'size' => $size, 
            ];
        });

        return $rows;
    }
}
```

3. Create a new filament page.

*app/Filament/Pages/Private.php*

```
class Private extends Page implements HasTable
{
    use InteractsWithTable;

    protected static string $view = 'filament.pages.private-files';

    public function table(Table $table): Table
    {
        return $table
            ->query(PrivateFilesWrapper::query())
            ->columns([
                TextColumn::make('name'),
                TextColumn::make('date'),
                TextColumn::make('size'),
            ])
            ->actions([
                DeleteAction::make('delete')
                    ->action(fn ($record) => Storage::disk('private_disk')->delete($record->name)),
            ]);
    }
}
```

*resources/views/filament/pages/private-files.blade.php*

```
<x-filament-panels::page>
{{ $this->table }}
</x-filament-panels::page>
```

4. Add the page to the AdminPanelProvider.